# Creating PDFs Online

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, pdf, rdlc

We are using Report Definition laguage (RDL) templates to define various reports in one of our Sharepoint applications.  These reports are (then) saved as PDFs into various SharePoint Document Library's.  One report in-particular renders, but is considered to be "failing" due to the styling needs of the report.  So it appears RDL only understand "very simple" HTML.

**For Example:**

1. Trademark characters are not rendering as superscript (they render as normal text instead)
2. The ability to assign Line Height fails
3. The ability to assign Word Spacing fails (so printers "leading" requirements fail)

Both of these point to various marked Microsoft limitation for RDL's to interprint various HTML...of which we are now aware.

**So...**

I need a better tool...and we are scratching our heads on this one!

**QUESTION:**
What tools take-in HTML, understand CSS (well!) and can generate PDFs from C-Sharp objects?

Please keep in-mind I need the to PDF generator tools you recommend (below) to understand CSS and HTML.

**NOTE:**
I looked at the various other StackEchange sites to see if there is a better forum for this particular question, but this one was the only one that seemed to fit-the-bill.  If you are a mediator, and feel this question is mis-placed, please feel free to move this question.

Comment: It's not very clear what you want to accomplish ... are you trying to replace the "stock" PDF export feature, do you want to write a custom webapp to download PDFs, do you want to fix RDL so it works with out-of-the-box PDF exporting function ... ? You might try to print them using PDFCreator or something similar, then upload the resulting file on Sharepoint Document Library (just an idea).

Comment: I need a list of alternative tools: thank you for your submission of 'PDF Creator'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [HTML to PDF converter](http://www.hiqpdf.com) has the most accurate conversion of a complex html/css page. There is also a demo to try the conversion with your html

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can give [Amyuni WebkitPDF](http://www.amyuni.com/en/developer/webkitpdf/) a try. It is a **Free** component for converting HTML+CSS into PDF files. From the home page:

- Directly convert HTML files into PDF without the use of a web browser or a printer driver
- Convert HTML files into XAML/XPS for rendering within Silverlight
- Integrate and deploy the HTML conversion feature within your applications
- Generate either a single continuous PDF page or split the HTML into multiple PDF pages

Amyuni WebkitPDF is distributed as a library with a sample application, and sample code for C++ and C#.

*Disclaimer: I currently work as software developer at Amyuni Technologies.*

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Aspose.Pdf for .NET: http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.pdf-for-.net/default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I only know a workaround for the "leading space" issue. This example "leads" the value with 10 spaces:

```
=space(10) & Fields!FieldName.Value
```

This should work for any renderer, I'll update this if I come around other tricks.